# Bundles with large rank

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Suppose $E\to M$ is a vector bundle of rank $k$ bundle over an n-dimensional manifold. If $k>n$, is there a splitting $E\cong F\oplus G$ where the rank of $F$ is $n$ and the rank of $G$ is $k-n$? If so, is there always a splitting such that $G$ is trivial?

Comment: The answer is yes to both. Do you know about universal bundles?

Comment: Not yet! I've only read up to chapter 4 of Milnor-Stasheff.

Comment: The only way I know to understand this result is to use universal bundles and some homotopy theory, so I'd recommend you get acquainted with those first. The result is certainly not trivial. Perhaps somebody other than me knows a different approach, though.

Comment: I would still appreciate it if you posted it as an answer though, so I could come back to it one day.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of how this works.

1. Let $G_k$ be the set of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of countably infinite dimension, and $E_k\subseteq G_k\times\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the set of pairs $(V,x)$ with $x\in V$. The projection $p_k\colon E_k\rightarrow G_k$ on the first factor has  $p^{-1}(V)=\{V\}\times V$ for every $V\in G_k$, so the fibers naturally carry vector space structures. If you appropriately topologize these spaces, $p_k$ is a vector bundle of rank $k$, called the tautological bundle over $G_k$.
2. The bundle $E_k\rightarrow G_k$ is "universal" in the following sense. For any paracompact space $X$ (in particular, any manifold), there is a bijection $[X,G_k]\rightarrow\{\text{isomorphism classes of vector bundles over $X$}\}$ given by $[f]\mapsto f^{\ast}E_k$. In particular, the pullback depends up to isomorphism only on the homotopy class of $f$. If $E\rightarrow X$ is a vector bundle of rank $k$ and $f\colon X\rightarrow G_k$ a map (unique up to homotopy) such that $f^{\ast}E_k\cong E$, then we say that $f$ *classifies* $E$.
3. Let $s\colon\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be the shift map $(x_1,x_2,\dotsc)\mapsto(0,x_1,\dotsc)$. This yields a map $G_k\rightarrow G_{k+1}$ taking $V\mapsto \mathbb{R}e_1\oplus s(V)$. Iterating this, we obtain maps $i_{kn}\colon G_k\rightarrow G_n$ for $k\le n$. It is a good exercise to check that $i_{kn}^{\ast}E_n\cong(G_k\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k})\oplus E_k$ and conclude that if a map $f\colon X\rightarrow G_k$ classifies a bundle $E\rightarrow X$, then the composite $i_{kn}f\colon X\rightarrow G_n$ classifies $(X\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k})\oplus E\rightarrow X$.
4. Thus, putting 2. and 3. together, the question of whether a bundle $E\rightarrow X$ of rank $k$ splits as $E\cong(X\times\mathbb{R}^{k-n})\oplus F$ with $F\rightarrow X$ of rank $n$ (I'm sorry for switching the indices at this point) is equivalent to the question of whether a map $f\colon X\rightarrow G_k$ classifying $E$ factors through $i_{nk}$ *up to homotopy*, in other words if it represents an element in the image of $[X,G_n]\rightarrow[X,G_k]$.
5. The map $G_k\rightarrow G_{k+1}$ is fiber-homotopy equivalent to the sphere bundle of the universal bundle $E_{k+1}\rightarrow G_{k+1}$. Then, using the long exact sequence of this bundle, it follows that $G_k\rightarrow G_{k+1}$ induces isomorphisms on $\pi_n$ for $n<k$ and a surjection on $\pi_k$, i.e. it is $k$-connected.
6. If $X$ is a CW-complex of dimension $\le n$ and $f\colon Y\rightarrow Z$ is an $n$-connected map, then $[X,Y]\rightarrow[X,Z]$ is a surjection. This is a standard cell-by-cell induction argument.
7. If $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold, it has the homotopy type of a CW-complex of dimension $\le n$, so putting 2. and 6. together, the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Thorgott! Once I understand universal bundles and the necessary homotopy theory, I will accept this answer if no simpler answers come along.